# Instantiate gameObject on mouse input position goes to the center of map

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a large 3d cube. I want the player to be able to instantiate a game object wherever they want on this cube. If they click, I want the object to be created where their mouse currently is. For some reason, the object is always instantiated at 0,0,0 instead of where the mouse is.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlaceItems : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject wall;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray))
                Instantiate(wall, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help. It's the first project I'm working on and this has had me stuck for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `transform.position` is where *your script is attached to an object is located* not the ray's hit point.

You need to alter your raycast code to return a `RaycastHit` object will contain the point you want.

```
public class PlaceItems : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject wall;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
                Instantiate(wall, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```